# Что такое тонкий враппер?

Tags: классы, любой-язык, терминология

Что такое тонкий враппер? Так же в контексте встечалось сочетание "тонкий адаптер".

Comment: Добавьте метку ЯП.

Answer (score 10):

Под "тонкой обёрткой" обычно понимается адаптация какой-нибудь библиотеки или её фрагмента с минимальной доработкой под целевую среду (язык, фреймворк, и т. п.), просто "чтобы хоть как-то работало". За "минимальность" её и называют тонкой.

Из-за этого код, работающий с "тонкой обёрткой" максимально похож на код работы с оригиналом (та же семантика, похожий идиоматичный код, и т. п.), но при этом в целевой среде может выглядеть крайне необычно, неканонично или даже опасно, а потому и работать с такой обёрткой может быть сложнее и/или непривычнее.

Однако сделать такую обёртку банально проще и быстрее, и работать она в ряде случаев будет быстрее полноценной.

Детали, которые часто в "тонких обёртках" не реализуются:

- Приведение к родным для среды типам данных: работа либо в типах специально для этой библиотеки, реализованных в обёртке, либо в типах для FFI вообще.
- Каноничная обработка ошибок: банальное "исключения vs. возвращаемые коды ошибок".
- Строгие определения типов: возможно, придётся отказаться от части компиляторной магии, которая позволяет находить ошибки, связанные с типами.
- Интеграция с абстракциями языка. Интерфейсами коллекций, к примеру: какие-нибудь особые формы циклов, которые на них рассчитывают, могут для объектов из "тонкой обёртки" быть неприменимы.